# Elegant code to generate equally spaced time stamps for given period in R

Tags: r, datetime

What is an elegant way to generate a list of time-stamps for each quarter of an hour for a given period in R.

The function should have a year as input (e.g. 2015) and as give as output analig of

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-11-14 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),tz = "UTC")
```

for reach quarter of an hour of the specific year.

Comment: You are right, but there was nothing worth posting. I was not aware of seq.POSIXt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straight forward function, I think it'll always look a bit clumsy as you're specifying date and time.

```
count.up = function(year){
seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0(year, "-01-01 00:00:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),tz = "UTC"),
       to=as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0(year, "-12-31 23:45:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),tz = "UTC"),
       by="15 min")
}
```

And run with:

```
x = count.up(2015)
```

This generates a vector rather than list (as you ask for), but it's easily wrapped in `as.list()` to convert.

Comment: great, a vector is fine too!